# If $f(x): [0,1]\to R$ is cont., inj., with $-1<f(0)<f(1)<1$, how many functions $g(x): [-1,1]\to[0,1]$ with $g\circ f(x)=x$, $x\in[0,1]$ are there?

Tags: functions

According to the condition given, I figured out $f(x)$ is an increasing function with range a subset of $(-1,1)$, and from $g \circ f(x)=x$, $g(x)$ should be the inverse function of $x$.

For a function $f(x)$ there should be one $g(x)$. So my answer was $1$, but the answer given is infinite. I am unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if $g(-1)=0$? What if $g(-1)=1$? What if $g(-1)=0.1$? It turns out you can arbitrarily change the value of $g(-1)$, and the equation $g\circ f(x)=x$ still holds, because $f(x)$ is never equal to $-1$.

Comment: I got your point.Thank you for solving my problem